# Cannot start closure function in the WebSocket

Tags: javascript, websocket, closures

I cannot start closure function in the WebSocket. So, I write the funciton that must increment the counter `index` bby one each time when socket event fired (ADD_USER). But it's does not happen... What is I missed?

```
wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
    let index = 0;
    function indexInc() { // this one
        return function() {
            console.log(index); // ... does not invoke
            return index += 1;
        }
    }
    ws.on('message', (message) => {
        const data = JSON.parse(message)
        switch (data.type) {
            case 'ADD_USER': {
                indexInc() // does not start
                users.push({ name: data.name, id: index})
                ws.send(JSON.stringify({
                    type: 'USERS_LIST',
                    users
                }))
                broadcast({
                    type: 'USERS_LIST',
                    users
                }, ws)
                break
            }
```

Comment: You need to use `indexInc()()` in order for those statements to be invoked because `indexInc` returns a function.

Comment: @Titus thank you, it work's, but without incrementing on `case 'ADD_USER':` invoke ^(